# To get the response for the API using curl command using wiremock

Tags: curl, wiremock

I have the following request and response content.

REQUEST

```
HTTP/1.1 POST /identity/v1/users
Content‐Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
{
"firstName" : "foo", "lastName" : "bar", "email" : "test@test.com", "password" : "secret123ABC"
}
```

RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created

{"id":111985014}
```

I was trying to use curl command to get the response but I am getting different errors and didn't understand how to do it. Please help if someone knows this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl -XPOST http://<your-domain>/identity/v1/users -H "Content‐Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"firstName" : "foo", "lastName" : "bar", "email" : "test@test.com", "password" : "secret123ABC"}'
```

Comment: I would like to know how it returns the response "id" for the answer you gave. When I tried it, it is throwing Connection refused error.

Comment: @user6348718 Did you change `<your-domain>` to real address ?

Comment: @user6348718 that looks like `wiremock` is not running or you are trying to connect to a wrong port.

Comment: When I ran that command I got 500 error saying Content-type not defined and also my doubt here is how do I get the response when I don't specify my response I want?